# Extend Gutenberg core/link results with custom link results

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm stuck trying to find right approach here, and have tried a few approaches out of which nothing worked.

Basically, when a user performs a search, I want to include custom results from 3rd party API that essentially would be simple links to other websites

Is there any way to achieve this without creating a custom block?
Open to any suggestions at this point.

[image: LinkUI]